# Is my application icon visible in the Windows notification area?

Tags: windows, winapi, taskbar, notification-area

My software has a notification icon. Windows hides inactive icons by default. When a user closes my application, I would like to inform them, that the application is still active in the background and they can reach it through the icon in the hidden notification area.

I would like to show this message *only* if the icon is indeed not visible.

Using `Shell_NotifyIconGetRect` doesn’t help much, because even if the icon is hidden, it still succeeds and returns the coordinates of the arrow icon.

Is there any other way to find out if my notification icon is currently visible or not?
Alternatively, is there a way to find out the coordinates of the arrow icon – then I could compare them with the coordinates I got looking for my icon. Or is there at least a way to find out if the arrow icon is shown at all (that would help me a little bit with a fallback solution).

Comment: Don't try to do this. Work with the system, not against it.

Comment: It may not be exactly what you want though, but you can determine if the arrow is there using UI Automation. The corresponding Automation Element is called the "Notification Chevron". There is a sample here on how to do this kind of stuff: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20141013-00/?p=43863

Comment: David, I'm just trying to create a user-friendly application. As long as MS doesn't offer a proper official solution for this use case, I don't see a better way. Not sure, what bothers you. @Simon Mourier Thanks, that might help me with a fallback solution.

Comment: I would like to use this condition for not bothering users who have moved the icon manually into the visible area and those who have all icons visible (by taskbar property or group policy). If auto-hide is enabled (default) the icon will be gone after some seconds while the application is being used.

Comment: @Codex the solution Simon proposes is based on *implementation details* that are subject to change at any time (like, for instance, when Microsoft introduced the ability to hide notification icons to begin with).  Microsoft does not provide any *official* APIs for what you are asking for, so you are going to end up relying on *undocumented and unofficial* APIs, which is not a good idea. I'm sure that is what David is referring to.

Comment: The thing is, users know about the notification area. You don't need to teach them that. Attempting to do so will just make your program messier.

Comment: There are so many different types of users that I'm afraid your general assumption barely touches the reality. I've seen users tapping on screens with their fingers because they forgot that their device has no touch screen. So yeah, there's that. And even as a more experienced user, I would like to be notified if a new application minimizes into a notification icon. You might see this differently, but in the end I'm just asking for help finding a solution for a functionality I would like to have in my software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using `Shell_NotifyIconGetRect` doesn’t help much, because even if the icon is hidden, it still succeeds and returns the coordinates of the arrow icon.

The result after my test is not like this.

I created a sample and used the following code:

```
static NOTIFYICONDATA nid;
static NOTIFYICONIDENTIFIER niif;
case WM_CREATE:
{
    nid.cbSize = sizeof(NOTIFYICONDATA);
    nid.hWnd = hwnd;
    nid.uID = 1001;
    nid.uCallbackMessage = WM_MYMESSAGE;
    nid.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_QUESTION);
    strcpy(nid.szTip, "Test Tool");
    nid.uFlags = NIF_MESSAGE | NIF_ICON | NIF_TIP;
    nid.dwStateMask = NIS_HIDDEN;
    size_t nidszTipLength = sizeof(nid.szTip) / sizeof(nid.szTip[0]);
    Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, &nid);
    niif.cbSize = sizeof NOTIFYICONIDENTIFIER;
    niif.hWnd = nid.hWnd;
    niif.uID = nid.uID;
    niif.guidItem = GUID_NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

Then I use Shell_NotifyIconGetRect to get the coordinates of the icon:

```
RECT rc;
HRESULT hr = Shell_NotifyIconGetRect(&niif, &rc);
```

When the icon is in the hidden area:

[image]

When I modify its location:

[image]

It can be seen that even in the hidden area, the coordinates of the icon can be obtained through the `Shell_NotifyIconGetRect` function.

Similarly, I tested the situation not in the hidden area:

[image]

You can find that the size and coordinates of the icon have changed, and you can judge whether the icon is in the hidden area based on them.

**Edit：**

When the hidden area is closed:

If the icon is displayed in the notification area, the `Shell_NotifyIconGetRect` function returns `S_OK`:

[image]

If the icon is in the hidden area of the notification area, the function returns `S_FALSE`:

[image]

Comment: So what's your result, when the icon is actually hidden? (in hidden area and the hidden area is closed)

Comment: @CodeX I have updated my answer.You can refer to it.

Comment: You seem to be right! Although rc contains the coordinates of the arrow, the actual result is indeed 1 instead of 0. I'm a bit confused, because I have used this function in another project a couple of years ago and my results were, that the function even suceeds if the icon is hidden. I don't know if I was mistaken back then or if they changed the function, but it would definitely solve my problem! I will test this later with an old Win10 VM and with Win7 to see if there is a difference and let you know.

Comment: Just as a small addition, the person in this thread experienced the same issue as me (back then): https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/3ec800fa-9335-4aa7-b594-a79569fdc6c2

Comment: Don't have my old Win10-VM anymore, but in Win7 it works the same way as in the latest Win10 version. Apparently, I was only paying attention to the result coordinates (which return the arrow rect if the icon is hidden) but not the HRESULT value, which tells if the icon was found or not, as you have correctly stated in your update. Thanks a lot!